# How can code to present this following matrices

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

I am doing my research. I have problem to make code to present this following matrices.

```
A(:,:,1)=[ 1 2 3 4;
           3 2 1 4]
A(:,:,2)=[ 1 3 4 2;
           4 2 1 3]

C(:,:,1)=[ 0 0 1 2;
           1 1 1 0]
C(:,:,2)=[ 1 0 1 0;
           0 1 1 1]
```

Matrices C is matrices that show how many zeros before value in matrice A.

And i have this following matrices to present value in matrices A.

```
value=1, 
B(1)=[1 1 1;
      1 1 1]
value=2,
B(2)=[2 2 2;
      2 2 2]
value=3,
B(3)=[3 3 3;
      4 4 4]
value=4,
B(4)=[4 4 4;
      3 3 3]
```

So that I will get this following matrices by combining A and C.

```
Res(:,:,1)=[1 1 1 2 2 2 0 3 3 3 0 0 4 4 4;
            1 1 1 2 2 2 0 4 4 4 0 0 3 3 3;
            0 3 3 3 0 2 2 2 0 1 1 1 4 4 4;
            0 4 4 4 0 2 2 2 0 1 1 1 3 3 3]

Res(:,:,2)=[0 1 1 1 3 3 3 0 4 4 4 2 2 2 0;
            0 1 1 1 4 4 4 0 3 3 3 2 2 2 0;
            4 4 4 0 2 2 2 0 1 1 1 0 3 3 3;
            3 3 3 0 2 2 2 0 1 1 1 0 4 4 4]
```

I got this following from other forum.

```
CP = bsxfun(@minus, 3 , sum(C,2));
G = mat2cell(C,ones(size(C,1),1),ones(size(C,2),1),ones(size(C,3),1));
CP = mat2cell(CP,ones(size(CP,1),1),ones(size(CP,2),1),ones(size(CP,3),1));
D = B(A);
E = cellfun(@(x,n) [zeros(size(x,1),n) x], D, G,'UniformOutput',false);
for ii=1:depth;
    E(:,end,ii) = cellfun(@(x,n) [x,zeros(size(x,1),n)],E(:,end,ii),CP(:,:,ii),...
   'UniformOutput',false);
    NewMatrice(:,:,ii)=cell2mat(E(:,:,ii));
end
```

What is your Opinion?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking for. This is not matlab code. What does 'present a matrix' mean? And why is this tagged 'Performance'?

Comment: @LucasKeaton : what did you mean mr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, I don't understand how your matrix `A` both holds the first `A = [ 1 2 3 4; 3 2 1 4]` and `A(1)`, `A(2)`, `A(3)` and `A(4)` at the same time.

I suppose that you have the following instead:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4; 3, 2, 1, 4];
B(:, :, 1) = [1, 1, 1; 1, 1, 1];
B(:, :, 2) = [2, 2, 2; 2, 2, 2];
B(:, :, 3) = [3, 3, 3; 4, 4, 4];
B(:, :, 4) = [4, 4, 4; 3, 3, 3];
```

Assuming this, you can get your desired result in the following way:

```
Res = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(n)B(:, :, n), A, 'UniformOutput', false));
```

which yields:

```
Res =

     1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3     4     4     4
     1     1     1     2     2     2     4     4     4     3     3     3
     3     3     3     2     2     2     1     1     1     4     4     4
     4     4     4     2     2     2     1     1     1     3     3     3
```

#### EDIT #1:

Following the update to your question, if you have another matrix `C = [0, 0, 1, 2; 1, 1, 1, 0]` that represents the number of leading zeros to insert before the `B` matrices, you can get your desired result in the following way:

```
my_func = @(n)[zeros(size(B(:, :, A(n)), 1), C(n)), B(:, :, A(n))];
Res = cell2mat(arrayfun(my_func, reshape(1:numel(A), size(A)), 'Uniform', false))
```

this yields:

```
Res =

  Columns 1 through 15

     1    1    1    2    2    2    0    3    3    3    0    0    4    4    4
     1    1    1    2    2    2    0    4    4    4    0    0    3    3    3
     0    3    3    3    0    2    2    2    0    1    1    1    4    4    4
     0    4    4    4    0    2    2    2    0    1    1    1    3    3    3
```

#### EDIT #2:

Following the second update to your question, if your `A` and `C` matrices are 3-dimensional, this adds a lot of complexity to the code. I find it easiest to use a `for` loop and reduce the problem to 2-D, like so:

```
for k = 1:size(A, 3)
    A2 = A(:, :, k);
    C2 = C(:, :, k);
    my_func = @(n)[zeros(size(B(:, :, A2(n)), 1), C2(n)), B(:, :, A2(n))];
    Res(:,:,k) = cell2mat(arrayfun(my_func,reshape(1:numel(A2),size(A2)),'Un',0))
end
```

If you want different sizes for `Res` in each iteration, I suggest you make `Res` a cell array, *i.e.*:

```
Res{k} = cell2mat(arrayfun(my_func,reshape(1:numel(A2),size(A2)),'Un',0))
```

P.S.
Notice that for the second iteration you have `C = [1, 0, 1, 0; 0, 1, 1, 1]` you'll get a problem, because the second row won't have the same amount of zeroes as the first. I believe you meant something like this: `C = [1, 1, 1, 0; 0, 1, 1, 1]`.

#### EDIT #3:

Here's code to generate a random matrix `C`, where each row sums up to a predefined integer `K` (which is also chosen arbitrarily):

```
K = fix(size(A, 2) * (1 + rand));                         %# Pick a random K
C = rand(size(A));                                        %# Generate a random C
C = ceil(C * K ./ repmat(sum(C, 2), 1, size(A, 2))) - 1;  %# Normalize
C(:, end) = C(:, end) + K - sum(C, 2);                    %# Fix illegal rows
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Mr. if I add another matrice like my edited post, how can I modify your code??

Comment: What is the relationship between your new matrix `C` and the result?

Comment: Matrix C is matrix that show how many zeros before Value A. example if we ignore B so we have A=[1...;3...] then C=[0...;1...] so that in the result will be res=[1...;0 3...]. before value 3 has zeros first.

Comment: how can I modify your code for 3 dimension size matrix mr. because actually my matrix A and C is 3 dimension matrix. I have tried to change little bit in your code. but it didnt work always.

Comment: I suggest you reformulate you question so that it describes your problem as accurately as possible, while still being short and concise. I cannot provide helpful answers if you're describing just a part of the question and plan to modify the question many times.

Comment: @engineering2008: Why don't you just use the code by EitanT for every index in the 3. dimension separately and concatenate the results afterwards?

Comment: @Mehrwolf: I had tried already. but my edited code did not work. you mean that I just add index 3 dimension right in every matrix A and C right?

Comment: @EitanT: Mr. actualy every row in C has not same amount of zeros. because I got that matrix by randoming.

Comment: @EitanT : what did this error mean? "??? Error using ==> cell2mat at 55
Cannot support cell arrays containing cell arrays or objects."

Comment: I mean the same amount of zeros _in each row in matrix `A`_. For example: For `C = [1 0 1 0; 0 1 1 1]`, the corresponding matrix `A` would have 14 elements in the first row, but 15 elements in the second row -- This matrix would be illegal.

Comment: @EitanT: can i make matrix what i want with another way or not? because my matrix c is random so i cannot make sure that the first and second or another row will have same amount.

Comment: @EitanT: see my updated post, I got it from another forum. it is right code for me. what is your opinion? you have another code faster?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I've added code to generate a legal matrix `C`. Regarding the code that you found in a forum -- I'm sorry, but I cannot get it to run (it seems to have several errors in it). If it works for you, then it works for you.